# How to call and print methods

Tags: java

I have my main class `Date.Java`

`Date.Java` does:
-sets month date and year, and makes sure their valid inputs
-determines how many days are in the month you enter
-determines how many days have passed since the day you enter
-determines how many days are left from the day you enter
-determines if the year is a leap year or not

I also have a testing class `TestDate.java`
-It asks the user for the inputs and sends them to `Date.java`

My issue is I can only get the program to print the date the user enters. How would I go about calling the other methods and having them print what they are returning?

**Date.java**:

```java
public class Date
 {
int Day;
int Month;
int Year;
int numberOfDays;
int daysPassed;
int daysRemaining;
int M;
int D;
int Y;



public Date (int Day, int Month, int Year)          
{  
  setDate(Month, Day, Year);

}

public void setDate (int Day, int Month, int Year)
{
    setMonth(Month);
    setDay(Day);
    setYear(Year);
}


//-------------------SETTERS----------------------
public void setMonth(int Month)
{
    M = ((Month>0&&Month<13) ?Month:1);      //conditional statement that checks to see if the Month is valid
}

public void setDay(int Day)
{
    D = ((Day>=1&&Day<=365) ?Day:1);      //conditional statement that checks to see if the day is valid

}

public void setYear(int Year)
{
    Y = ((Year>=1000&&Year<=9999) ?Year:1900);      //conditional statement that checks to see if the Year is valid
}

  //-------------------GETTERS----------------------
public int getMonth()
{
    return M;

}

public int getDay()
{
    return D;

}


public int getYear()
{
    return Y;
}

public String toString()
{
    return String.format("%d-%d-%d", getMonth(), getDay(), getYear());
}

public static boolean isLeapYear(int getYear)
{

    if (getYear%4 == 0)
        return true;


    else
        return false;



}

public int daysOfMonth(int getMonth, int numberOfDays, boolean isLeapYear)
{
    if (getMonth==1)        //jan
       numberOfDays = 31;

    //---------------------------------------Feb
    if (isLeapYear == true) //feb
    {
    if (getMonth==2)
       numberOfDays = 29;
    }
    if (isLeapYear == false) //feb
    {
    if (getMonth==2)
       numberOfDays = 28;
    }
    //---------------------------------------Feb

    if (getMonth==3)        //march
       numberOfDays = 31;
    if (getMonth==4)        //april 
       numberOfDays = 30;
    if (getMonth==5)        //may
       numberOfDays = 31;
    if (getMonth==6)        //june
       numberOfDays = 30;
    if (getMonth==7)        //july
       numberOfDays = 31;
    if (getMonth==8)        //august
       numberOfDays = 31;
    if (getMonth==9)        //sept
       numberOfDays = 30;
    if (getMonth==10)       //oct
       numberOfDays = 31;
    if (getMonth==11)       //nov
       numberOfDays = 30;
    if (getMonth==12)       //dec
       numberOfDays = 31;   


    return numberOfDays;
}

public int daysPassedInYear(int getMonth, int Day, int getDay, int numberOfDays, boolean isLeapYear)
{
    if (getMonth==1)
    Day = getDay-31;


    if (isLeapYear = true)
    {
    if (getMonth==2)
    daysPassed = (numberOfDays-getDay)-60;
    if (getMonth==3)
    daysPassed = (numberOfDays-getDay)-91;
    if (getMonth==4)
    daysPassed = (numberOfDays-getDay)-121;
    if (getMonth==5)
    daysPassed = (numberOfDays-getDay)-152;
    if (getMonth==6)
    daysPassed = (numberOfDays-getDay)-182;
    if (getMonth==7)
    daysPassed = (numberOfDays-getDay)-213;
    if (getMonth==8)
    daysPassed = (numberOfDays-getDay)-244;
    if (getMonth==9)
    daysPassed = (numberOfDays-getDay)-274;
    if (getMonth==10)
    daysPassed = (numberOfDays-getDay)-305;
    if (getMonth==11)
    daysPassed = (numberOfDays-getDay)-335;
    if (getMonth==12)
    daysPassed = (numberOfDays-getDay)-366;
    }




    if (isLeapYear = false)
    {
    if (getMonth==2)
    daysPassed = (numberOfDays-getDay)-59;
    if (getMonth==3)
    daysPassed = (numberOfDays-getDay)-90;
    if (getMonth==4)
    daysPassed = (numberOfDays-getDay)-120;
    if (getMonth==5)
    daysPassed = (numberOfDays-getDay)-151;
    if (getMonth==6)
    daysPassed = (numberOfDays-getDay)-181;
    if (getMonth==7)
    daysPassed = (numberOfDays-getDay)-212;
    if (getMonth==8)
    daysPassed = (numberOfDays-getDay)-243;
    if (getMonth==9)
    daysPassed = (numberOfDays-getDay)-273;
    if (getMonth==10)
    daysPassed = (numberOfDays-getDay)-304;
    if (getMonth==11)
    daysPassed = (numberOfDays-getDay)-334;
    if (getMonth==12)
    daysPassed = (numberOfDays-getDay)-365;
    }


    return daysPassed;

}



    public int daysRemainingInYear(int dayspassed, boolean isLeapYear, int daysRemaining)
    {
        if (isLeapYear = true)      
            daysRemaining = (366 - dayspassed);


        if (isLeapYear = false)         
            daysRemaining = (365 - dayspassed);

        return daysRemaining;
    }






}
```

**TestDate.java**:

```java
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;



public class TestDate {
public static void main(String[] args) {


int month =Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What month do you want(in number form ex. Jan = 1?"));
int day =Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What day do you want within the month?"));
int year =Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What year do you want"));


Date setDateObject = new Date(month, day, year);
System.out.println(setDateObject.toString());

}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call the other methods on your Date object and print their return value.

```
Date date = new Date(1, 2, 2003);

System.out.println(date.getYear());
System.out.println(date.isLeapYear());
```

The way you use parameters is weird.. Parameters like getMonth, numberOfDays, isLeapYear are used to pass information into the function. getMonth and isLeapYear are essential to the function working correctly, but numberOfDays is not essential. You can declare the function like so:

```
public int daysOfMonth(int getMonth, boolean isLeapYear)
{
    if (getMonth==1)        //jan
       return 31;

    //---------------------------------------Feb
    if (isLeapYear && getMonth==2)
       return 29;
    }

    if (/* !isLeapYear && */ getMonth==2)
       return 29;
    }
    //---------------------------------------Feb

    if (getMonth==3)        //march
       return 31;
    if (getMonth==4)        //april 
       return 30;
    if (getMonth==5)        //may
       return 31;
    if (getMonth==6)        //june
       return 30;
    if (getMonth==7)        //july
       return 31;
    if (getMonth==8)        //august
       return 31;
    if (getMonth==9)        //sept
       return 30;
    if (getMonth==10)       //oct
       return 31;
    if (getMonth==11)       //nov
       return 30;
    if (getMonth==12)       //dec
       return 31;   


    return -1; // error
}
```

Then you can create a date like so and call the daysOfMonth function.

```
Date date = (2, 29, 2004);
System.out.println(date);
System.out.println("Is this date a leap year? " + date.isLeapYear());
System.out.println("How many days in this month? " + date.daysOfMonth(date.getMonth(), date.isLeapYear());
```

Comment: Is there any other way I can print the returns from the other methods like "public int daysOfMonth" or "public int daysPassedInYear"?

Comment: AWESOME! thank you so much! I totally realized what I am doing wrong now.

Answer (score 0):

Do

```
System.out.println(yourobject.yourMethod());
```

This will print what ever your method `yourMethod()` is returning.

Also you can print the values inside any function.

```
public void yourMethod(){
System.out.println(yourAtrribute);
}
```

**For your class you may do as following:**

```
Date setDateObject = new Date(month, day, year);
//do other stuffs here
System.out.println(setDateObject.getYear());
```

This will **print year** that your **getYear()** method is returning.